# Close the curent tab - IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, button

I want to close the current tab.

This is what I've got so far.

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">Close Me</a>
```

It displays a link. But I want to a button. How to use it in a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onClick` attribute of the button.

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">Close Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just `input` tag. Put script into its `onclick` attribute. Example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('','_self').close();" value="Close Me" />
```

There's no need for that `javascript:` part in `onclick` attribute. According to w3, using inputs outside forms is valid when you're using html version > 4.01:

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM
>   element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration
>   when they are used to build user interfaces. This is discussed in the
>   section on intrinsic events. Note that controls outside a form cannot
>   be successful controls.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls